# lspci shows soundcard, but nothing else does

Tags: drivers, 14.04, sound, realtek

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 on a computer with a [Gigabyte GA-990FXA-UD3 (rev 1.0)](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=3894#sp) motherboard.  This motherboard has a Realtek ALC889 "HD Audio" chip.  However, the volume control only shows "Dummy Output" and I do not hear any sound.

When I run `lspci`, the output includes the following line:

```
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)
```

When I run `` find /lib/modules/`uname -r` | grep snd ``, I see lines for a number of codecs, including `/lib/modules/3.13.0-29-generic/kernel/sound/pci/hda/snd-hda-codec-realtek.ko`, which I would have thought is the correct one.  `modprobe -c | grep realtek` shows that this codec is loaded.

I was going to try installing the [generic Realtek HD Audio driver](http://www.realtek.com.tw/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false#2), but I don't want to mess things up if there's a better way.

If it matters, I am using XFCE instead of Unity.

Comment: Perhaps this will help http://www.unixmen.com/2012003-howto-resolve-nosound-problem-on-ubuntu/

Comment: @Tuknutx thanks, but that doesn't help. In step 1, the only audio output device listed is "Dummy Output" so there's no help in adjusting the volume. In step 2, I get `cannot open mixer: No such file or directory`. In step 3, I get `Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: (none loaded).  Loading ALSA sound driver modules: (none to reload).` Step 4 says that it is not compatible with 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that trying to run `aplay -l` (as suggested in other places) returns the following message: `aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...`

A Google search for that text found [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/237232/34944) which solved my problem.

```
sudo modprobe snd-hda-intel
```