# No sound after Ubuntu 14.04 LTS update

Tags: 14.04, drivers, sound, alsa

I tried many things to recover the sound on my dell vostro 3559 pre-installed with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. however, nothing helping :-(

Followed all instructions from the below

[How to fix "No Soundcards Found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57810/how-to-fix-no-soundcards-found#new-answer?newreg=f73fffb7daa94856af0b62aeb2e93fab)

here is the o/p I got

```
$ lspci -v | grep -A7 -i "audio"
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9d70 (rev 21)
    Subsystem: Dell Device 06c2
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 255
    Memory at d1220000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=16K]
    Memory at d1200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [disabled] [size=64K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>

00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9d23 (rev 21)
```

Does this o/p show any issues with my drivers or do I need to enable something? Please help me with this. I am a beginner to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Same thing happened with my system. I think you enable Secure Booting .
Check following link, it helps me to solve the issue.
[Why do I get "Required key not available" when install 3rd party kernel modules or after a kernel upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/762254/why-do-i-get-required-key-not-available-when-install-3rd-party-kernel-modules)