# sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl driver: sound card not detected - DummyOutput in sound settings after broken firmware upgade: Failed to recover ME Firmware

Tags: sound, kernel, 22.04, lenovo, fwupd

I'm experiencing a sound issue on a Lenovo P15s laptop having Ubuntu 22.04.2**

There is actually no sound at all; the sound settings displaying a single "DummyOutput" entry:

[image]

I went trough several topics, the most relevant being:

- [How to fix "No Soundcards Found"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57810/how-to-fix-no-soundcards-found)
- [Upgrade from 21.04 to 22.04, audio lost (Dummy output only)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1407616/upgrade-from-21-04-to-22-04-audio-lost-dummy-output-only)

without success.

#### Here are some more information:

##### `inxi` output:

```
$ inxi -SMA

System:
  Host: localhost-ThinkPad Kernel: 5.19.0-35-generic x86_64
    bits: 64 Desktop: GNOME 42.5 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20W6004XMZ v: ThinkPad P15s Gen 2i
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: 20W6004XMZ v: SDK0J40697 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: LENOVO v: N34ET54W (1.54 )
    date: 11/21/2022
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Audio
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k5.19.0-35-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
```

##### Current state:

```
$ cat /proc/asound/cards 

--- no soundcards ---
```

```
$ sudo aplay -l

aplay: device_list:274: no soundcards found...
```

##### Relevant `lspci` output:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A2 Audio

00:1f.3 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [8086:a0c8] (rev 20)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller [17aa:22c9]
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

##### Some `lsmod` outputs:

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_hda_intel

snd_hda_intel          53248  0
snd_intel_dspcfg       36864  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_sof_intel_hda_common
snd_hda_codec         176128  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_soc_hdac_hda
snd_hda_core          114688  9 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_ext_core,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_soc_hdac_hda,snd_sof_intel_hda
snd_pcm               155648  11 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,soundwire_intel,snd_sof,snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_compress,snd_soc_core,snd_sof_utils,snd_hda_core,snd_pcm_dmaengine
snd                   114688  17 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_sof,snd_timer,snd_compress,thinkpad_acpi,snd_soc_core,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi
```

```
$ lsmod | grep snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl

snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl        16384  0
snd_sof_intel_hda_common    139264  1 snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_sof_pci                  24576  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
snd_soc_acpi_intel_match     69632  2 snd_sof_intel_hda_common,snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
```

##### Relevant `dmesg` output:

```
$ sudo dmesg | grep -e 'audio\|snd\|intel' 

[    1.247027] intel_pstate: Intel P-state driver initializing
[    1.247421] intel_pstate: HWP enabled
[    1.272390] intel_pmc_core INT33A1:00:  initialized
[    4.543674] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.694941] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-19-0-4.sfi
[    4.733324] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.742861] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    4.801068] intel_tcc_cooling: Programmable TCC Offset detected
[    4.823270] intel_rapl_msr: PL4 support detected.
[    4.824639] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain package
[    4.824641] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain core
[    4.824643] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain uncore
[    4.824644] intel_rapl_common: Found RAPL domain psys
[    4.954922] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380
[    4.956155] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+ platform, using SOF driver
[    4.956946] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040380
[    4.957054] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
[    4.963650] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode
[    4.984593] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5
[    4.984597] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now
[    4.984599] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables: 2
[    4.985395] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware info: version 2:0:0-b678a
[    4.985397] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Firmware: ABI 3:20:0 Kernel ABI 3:21:0
[    4.985400] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: unknown sof_ext_man header type 3 size 0x30
[    5.889516] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: cl_dsp_init: timeout with rom_status_reg (0x80000) read
[    5.890171] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: ------------[ DSP dump start ]------------
[    5.890876] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Boot iteration failed: 3/3
[    5.891678] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: fw_state: SOF_FW_BOOT_IN_PROGRESS (2)
[    5.892332] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: extended rom status:  0x6000021 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x25101c2 0x0
[    5.892967] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: ------------[ DSP dump end ]------------
[    5.894076] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: dsp init failed after 3 attempts with err: -110
[    5.895372] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Failed to start DSP
[    5.896586] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to boot DSP firmware -110
[    5.947739] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: hda_dsp_core_reset_enter: timeout on HDA_DSP_REG_ADSPCS read
[    5.948526] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: dsp core reset failed: core_mask 1
[    5.949602] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: sof_probe_work failed err: -110
[    6.494346] Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-19-0-4.ddc
```

---

** after a firmware upgrade which apparently went wrong because during each reboot it's now written something like

```
1) "Reading ME Firmware... Please do not power off! 50% Completed"
2) "Recovering ME Firmware...Please do not power off! 10% Completed"
3) "Failed to recover ME Firmware..."
```

I tried to reinstall the available firmware downloaded from here:

- cabfile: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n34rk01w.cab
- Readme: https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles/n34rk01w.txt

But surprisingly (!), Lenovo is not providing firmwares for Ubuntu 22.04:

[image]

And it simply doesn't work:

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr --allow-older --allow-reinstall install n34rk01w.cab

Decompressing…           [***************************************]
No supported devices found
```

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr --version

runtime   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9
runtime   com.dell.libsmbios            2.4
compile   org.freedesktop.gusb          0.3.10
runtime   org.kernel                    5.19.0-35-generic
compile   com.hughsie.libjcat           0.1.9
compile   org.freedesktop.fwupd         1.7.9
runtime   org.freedesktop.gusb          0.3.10
```

I am trying to be exhaustive, but I may have missed some crucial information. Don't hesitate to tell me if that's the case.

I simply want my sound card to work again normally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this by running the command suggested [here](https://github.com/fwupd/firmware-lenovo/issues/295#issuecomment-1362651135), by github user ruimbribeiro who had a same kind of issue on a Lenovo T14 Gen2i:

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr reinstall

Choose a device:
0.  Cancel
1.  2292ae5236790b47884e37cf162dcf23bfcd1c60 (Embedded Controller)
2.  349bb341230b1a86e5effe7dfe4337e1590227bd (Intel Management Engine)
3.  04e17fcf7d3de91da49a163ffe4907855c3648be (MZVLB1T0HBLR-000L7)
4.  0d5d05911800242bb1f35287012cdcbd9b381148 (Prometheus)
5.  73e606488fec47b3e3f9288094f66fded0051446 (Prometheus IOTA Config)
6.  a45df35ac0e948ee180fe216a5f703f32dda163f (System Firmware)
7.  362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590 (UEFI dbx)
2 <-- picking the second entry
# (...)
# reboot
```

Then, during the system reboot, I faced the same errors again:

```
1) "Reading ME Firmware... Please do not power off! 50% Completed"
2) "Recovering ME Firmware...Please do not power off! 10% Completed"
3) "Failed to recover ME Firmware..."
```

But this is normal, at this stage the system is not aware of the existence of the change I asked in the `fwupdmgr reinstall` command.

After that it passed by the splashscreen and then the screen stays black for roughly 1-2min.

It finally prints "System Reset" on the top-left.

And it rebooted again. Normally this time.

Everything is working fine now.